# HtmlWindow.Error event won't fire on Javascript error

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, error-handling, browser

I'm working on a WinForms control that wraps a Javascript API using a `WebBrowser` control, so I need to trap Javascript errors and convert them to exceptions.

```
_browser.Navigated += BrowserNavigated;
_browser.DocumentText = "...";

private void BrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e) {
    _browser.Document.Window.Error += ScriptError;
}

private void ScriptError(object sender, HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Description);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I know this method doesn't work if the page is refreshed, but that will never happen in my case, so I'm trying to keep things simple. The `BrowserNavigated` method is executed after setting `DocumentText`, but when an error occurs, the `ScriptError` method doesn't get called.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Attaching the `Error` handler in the `DocumentCompleted` event instead of `Navigated` now fires the script error handler for *some* errors. However, if a Javascript file specified by a `<script>` tag fails to load and then I try to use a function from it, I still get the generic error dialog.

This is main case in which I need to catch the error, because if the Javascript file doesn't load, it means the user's API key is invalid. How is this error different from the others?

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the handler for ScriptError outside the BrowserNavigated Event like you did for `_browser.Navigated += BrowserNavigated;`.. What currently happening is when BrowserNavigated fires then only the handler gets attached.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `HtmlDocument` will be available until the `Navigated` event has fired.